# Admob Interstitials Error

Tags: android, admob, andengine

i wanted to call the Admob interstitials? multiple time in my Android app.  i am tottally confusing this things.

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "ID");
        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

i am tried this code this works fine for one time call. when it will call second time show me error.

help me out this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe add the logcat of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate out construction of the Interstitial, loading the ad and showing the ad.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "MY-AD-ID");
  interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListsner() {
     ..
  });
}

private void loadAd() {
  final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void showAd() {
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
  }
}
```